# how to solve using NSString as NSNumber or using NSNumber as NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting

In my project, too many old code, which sometimes cause a problem about variable class mistake.

In most cases, a **NSNumber variable** is assigned by a **NSString value**, and vise versa. and later the variable uses some NSNumber method and crashes.

some times I use the below code

```
NSNumber *feed_id = nil;
id object = self.config.operationData.feedID;
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    feed_id = object;
} else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    feed_id = [(NSString *)object numberValue];
}
```

but I think it's not a comfortable way to handle it, because I don't know where has the problem, and using this code everywhere seems a little bit stupid.

So I need a smart way to detect the problem and if possible cast the variable type to the type I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got the code that will accept either type and give you back a NSNumber... all you need to do is to make it easy to use. You could put it in a method in a category on NSNumber, like:

```
@interface NSNumber (BandAid)
+ (NSNumber*)numberFromNumberOrString:(id)numberOrString;
@end

@implementation NSNumber (BandAid)
+ (NSNumber*)numberFromNumberOrString:(id)numberOrString {
    NSNumber *number = nil;
    if ([numberOrString isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        number = object;
    }else if ([numberOrString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        number = [(NSString *)object numberValue];
    }
    return number
}
@end
```

Now you can easily call:

```
NSNumber *feed_id = [NSNumber numberFromNumberOrString:self.config.operationData.feedID];
```

and similar elsewhere in you code. More importantly, you can add debug code to that method to help you track down all the places where a string is incorrectly passed, so that you can eliminate the sources of the problem rather than just putting a bandaid on it.

Other things you can/should do include:

- turn on all compiler warnings
- eliminate any warnings produced by your code
- add [validation methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/ValidatingProperties.html) to check the data that flows into your app

Answer (score 1):

Both `NSNumber` and `NSString` respond to `integerValue`, so if the value is supposed to be an integer this is a reliable way

```
id object = self.config.operationData.feedID;
NSNumber *feed_id = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: object.integerValue];
```

But I recommend to refactor the entire code to become type safe.